# How to capture part of a ScrollView as its content is scrolling?

Tags: android, bitmap, scrollview, capture

After extending the `ScrollView` class I was able to easily be notified of the scrolling in realtime.

Now I need to capture the content of this scrollview in a very specific part.
Let's say I want to capture the top of the screen (**matching parent width** and a defined height, like 100dp). But only the content of the ScrollView and not the rest, if there is anything else on the top but not as part of the ScrollView.

I tried using on the scrollview :

1. `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);`
2. `getDrawingCache(true);`
3. `setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);`

Then I tried to crop so that I get the part I want :

`Bitmap.createBitmap(complete, 0, 0, width, height);`

Results are very far from what I want to achieve and performance are very very poor and at some point I would get either a `SIGENV` or `getDrawingCache(true)` tries to use a recycled bitmap...

So how can I easily capture the content in the desired area without too much performance hit ?

Note: this process must be done as I am scrolling the content, so inside ScrollView's `onScrollChanged(final int x, final int y)`.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem was fun I implemented it, it seems to work fine. I guess that you are recreating a Bitmap each time that's why goes slow.
The idea is like this, you create an area in the ScrollView that you want to copy (see `Rect cropRect` and `Bitmap screenshotBitmap`), it's full width and you just need to set the height. The view automatically set a scroll listener on itself and on every scroll it will copy that area. Note that `setDrawingCacheEanbled(true)` is called just once when the view is instantiated, it basically tells the view that you will call `getDrawingCache()`, which will return the Bitmap on which the view is drawing itself. It then copy the area of interest on screenshotBitmap and that's the Bitmap that you might want to use.

ScreenshottableScrollView.java

```
package com.example.lelloman.screenshottablescrollview;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

/**
 * Created by lelloman on 16-2-16.
 */
public class ScreenshottableScrollView extends ScrollView implements ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener {

    public interface OnNewScreenshotListener {
        void onNewScreenshot(Bitmap bitmap);
    }

    private Bitmap screenshotBitmap = null;
    private Canvas screenshotCanvas = null;
    private int screenshotHeightPx = 0;
    private OnNewScreenshotListener listener = null;
    private Rect cropRect;
    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);


    public ScreenshottableScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ScreenshottableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ScreenshottableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ScreenshottableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(this);
    }

    public void setOnNewScreenshotListener(OnNewScreenshotListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        if(screenshotHeightPx != 0)
            makeScrenshotBitmap(w,h);
    }

    public void setScreenshotHeightPx(int q){
        screenshotHeightPx = q;
        makeScrenshotBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    private void makeScrenshotBitmap(int width, int height){

        if(screenshotBitmap != null) screenshotBitmap.recycle();

        if(width == 0 || height == 0) return;

        screenshotBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, screenshotHeightPx, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        screenshotCanvas = new Canvas(screenshotBitmap);

        cropRect = new Rect(0,0,width,screenshotHeightPx);


    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        if(listener == null) return;

        Bitmap bitmap = getDrawingCache();

        screenshotCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

        screenshotCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,cropRect, cropRect,paint);
        listener.onNewScreenshot(screenshotBitmap);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.lelloman.screenshottablescrollview.MainActivity">

    <com.example.lelloman.screenshottablescrollview.ScreenshottableScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.example.lelloman.screenshottablescrollview.ScreenshottableScrollView>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="#ff000000"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.lelloman.screenshottablescrollview;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        Random random = new Random();
        String AB = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ";

        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            builder.append("\n\n"+Integer.toString(i)+"\n\n");
            for(int j =0;j<1000;j++){
                builder.append(AB.charAt(random.nextInt(AB.length())));
            }
        }

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(builder.toString());
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        ScreenshottableScrollView scrollView = (ScreenshottableScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        scrollView.setScreenshotHeightPx((int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 100));

        scrollView.setOnNewScreenshotListener(new ScreenshottableScrollView.OnNewScreenshotListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNewScreenshot(Bitmap bitmap) {
                Log.d("MainActivity","onNewScreenshot");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much ! It works ! However performance is bad and the scrolling appears to be slow. However, it does not seem to be reflected on the GPU Monitor in Android Studio because I never go further the green line (16ms) that guarantees a constant 60 FPS. Weird, right ? Anyway, is there a way to keep my scrolling smooth ? Furthermore It seems that if I scroll fast, the screenshot is too out of sync which is a pity. I hope I improve the process. Thank you very much !!

Comment: testing your code, it would seem that the line `getDrawingCache();` is the culprit... so I guess there is nothing much to do ? :/

Comment: I'm glad that it helped, now I will add some explanation. About the performance, I don't know how you can do it better but it also depends on what are you doing with the Bitmap. Anyway please consider to accept the answer if it solved your problem ^^

Comment: Alright but what about capturing the background of the view? Let's say  I wish to capture the background of  the header (hence the top part mentioned in my question)? Would it not make the process easier and faster rather than capturing the whole ScrollView (the whole screen)? Is it even possible? I am not sure it's possible. The reason here is that I want to apply a filter in this header. Meaning any content that goes behind this header (in this case, the ScrollView content) must have the filter applied upon. That why I  asked this question. Do you think I can achieve this much?

Comment: Okay ^^ My Activity is made of two elements : a header and a ScrollView. Obviously the header does not move and displays information relative to the content of the ScrollView. The ScrollView contains data and you can scroll it. Thing is the ScrollView takes the whole screen but the header remains above still. I am supposed to apply a filter behind this header meaning it will be applied to the ScrollView content that goes behind the header. So my question is : can I capture what is behind the header only without having to capture the whole ScrollView (screen) then cropping it? Thanks!

Comment: I think that getDrawingCache is the way, cropping is not that computationally expensive anyway

Comment: I agree. But I commented out all the code following getDrawingCache and the performance hit was exactly the same. This is why I said getDrawingCache is the culprit. Is there anything I can do to speedup the process? Thanks :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's the minimum amount of computation you must have to achieve this goal. Btw, did you commented also imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); ?

Comment: Yes ! really commented out any operations following getDrawingCache() ^^

Comment: Ok so I'm sorry but I can't help you anymore, if you want to read the drawing of a view this should be the way to go.

Comment: alright thank you you've been a great help ! Your answer is accepted :)

Comment: Sorry to bother again but reading documentation about `getDrawingCache()` I stumbled upon this interesting part : `To benefit from the cache, you must request the drawing cache by calling this method and draw it on screen if the returned bitmap is not null.` how can I draw it on screen ? Apparently as of now I am drawing my `ScrollView` twice... hence the low performance result. What do you think ?

Comment: Yea it really makes sense, unfortunately i don't know how and couldn't find a solution online. If you do find one, please update me xD

Comment: Alright but it the mean time I detected a crucial caveat in the current solution : the memory usage simply doubles when starting making screenshots which would make sense as the ScrollView seems to draw twice, so twice the information in the heap... so unless I find the solution, I will have to discard yours ^^ but nonetheless, yours works ! ;-)

Comment: I think you're right, but the documentation is kind of generic about it and I can't find any example. If you find a proper way please update me!