# webview saves same screenshot again android

Tags: android, webview, screenshot

The below code captures the webview image and save it in Pictures folder. The code is as follows

```
public static void getBitmapOfWebView(final WebView webView){
    Date now = new Date();
    String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + "Screenshot_" + now + ".jpg";

    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Picture picture = webView.capturePicture();
    Bitmap  b = Bitmap.createBitmap( webView.getWidth(), webView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

    picture.draw(c);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {

        fos = new FileOutputStream(mPath);
        if ( fos != null ) {
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {}

    b.recycle();
}
```

The above code works and saves the screenshot in the pictures folder. But the problem is when i scroll down the WebView and try to execute the same code again, it saves the old screenshot of the webview in the pictures folder.

How do i code in such a way that when i scroll the Webview, it should save the current screenshot of the webview.

Any help Appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: instead if that you can take whole webview screenshot at a time like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230181/anroid-take-screenshot-of-whole-webview-in-nougat-android-7/45230400#45230400

Comment: I think this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435530/how-to-capture-part-of-a-scrollview-as-its-content-is-scrolling

Comment: no, it didnt work.

Comment: does it takes new screenshot of updated view but when saving, it saves old screenshot OR it isn't taking updated screenshot at all?

Comment: its not taking updated views at all ....

Comment: try by putting webview inside any otherview i.e. LinearLayout and apply the same code on that to capture screenshot and check

Comment: and in end of method 
  webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    webView.buildDrawingCache(false);

make it false